# Pandas - Duplicate Row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates

I'm trying to create a duplicate row if the row meets a condition. In the table below, I created a cumulative count based on a groupby, then another calculation for the MAX of the groupby.

```
df['PathID'] = df.groupby(DateCompleted).cumcount() + 1
df['MaxPathID'] = df.groupby(DateCompleted)['PathID'].transform(max)

Date Completed    PathID    MaxPathID
1/31/17           1         3
1/31/17           2         3
1/31/17           3         3
2/1/17            1         1
2/2/17            1         2
2/2/17            2         2
```

In this case, I want to duplicate only the record for 2/1/17 since there is only one instance for that date (i.e. where the MaxPathID == 1).

Desired Output:

```
Date Completed    PathID    MaxPathID
1/31/17           1         3
1/31/17           2         3
1/31/17           3         3
2/1/17            1         1
2/1/17            1         1
2/2/17            1         2
2/2/17            2         2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your desired output does _not_ have a duplicate of `2/1/17`. The rows in the output differ from the original row in PathID and MaxPathID. Please explain exactly what you want to get (not by example, but algorithmically).

Comment: How are you getting `MaxPathID` for the duplicate?

Comment: You can create exact duplicates with `df.append(df[df['MaxPathID']==1])`, but this is apparently not what you are looking for.

Comment: DYZ--you are correct. I modified the output to change the MaxPathID for the duplicated row. The final output doesn't have to be this way. I just want to duplicate the row where MaxPathID == 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need get `unique` rows by `Date Completed` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) rows to original:

```
df1 = df.loc[~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False), ['Date Completed']]
print (df1)
  Date Completed
3         2/1/17

df = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True).sort_values('Date Completed')
df['PathID'] = df.groupby('Date Completed').cumcount() + 1
df['MaxPathID'] = df.groupby('Date Completed')['PathID'].transform(max)
print (df)
  Date Completed  PathID  MaxPathID
0        1/31/17       1          3
1        1/31/17       2          3
2        1/31/17       3          3
3         2/1/17       1          2
6         2/1/17       2          2
4         2/2/17       1          2
5         2/2/17       2          2
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
  Date Completed  a  b
0        1/31/17  4  5
1        1/31/17  3  5
2        1/31/17  6  3
3         2/1/17  7  9
4         2/2/17  2  0
5         2/2/17  6  7

df1 = df[~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False)]
#alternative - boolean indexing by numpy array
#df1 = df[~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False).values]
print (df1)
  Date Completed  a  b
3         2/1/17  7  9

df = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True).sort_values('Date Completed')
print (df)
  Date Completed  a  b
0        1/31/17  4  5
1        1/31/17  3  5
2        1/31/17  6  3
3         2/1/17  7  9
6         2/1/17  7  9
4         2/2/17  2  0
5         2/2/17  6  7
```

Comment: That works perfectly! One more question--I have other columns in my dataframe (that I didn't show in my dataframe mockup), but when I duplicate the row, the values in the other columns are null. How do I ensure all values from all columns are copied and duplicated?

Comment: If multiple columns then need only change `df1 = df.loc[~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False), ['Date Completed']]` to `df1 = df[~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: Maybe add `values` - `df1 = df[~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False).values]`.

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A creative `numpy` approach using `duplicated` + `repeat`

```
dc = df['Date Completed']
rg = np.arange(len(dc)).repeat((~dc.duplicated(keep=False).values) + 1)
df.iloc[rg]

  Date Completed  PathID  MaxPathID
0        1/31/17       1          3
1        1/31/17       2          3
2        1/31/17       3          3
3         2/1/17       1          1
3         2/1/17       1          1
4         2/2/17       1          2
5         2/2/17       2          2
```

Comment: As pandas code: `df.loc[df.index.repeat((~df['Date Completed'].duplicated(keep=False)).add(1))]`

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a little bit of a different problem but it does match question description, so people will come from goolge. I haven't looked into optimizing below or anything like that, I am sure there is a better way, but sometimes just have to embrace imperfections ;) so just posting here in case somebody faces similar and wants to try fast and done. Seemed to work fairly fast.

Suppose we have dataframe (df) like so:

[image]

And we want to transform it to something like this given condition that field3 has more than one entry and we want to expand all entries within like so:

[image]

Here is one approach for that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date,datetime

index = []
double_values = []


### get index and get list of values on which to expand per indexed row
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    index.append(i)
    ### below transform your column with multiple entries to a list based on delimetter
    double_values.append(str(r[2]).split(' '))

serieses = []

print('tot row to process', len(index))
count = 0
for i,dvs in zip(index,double_values):
    count+= 1
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print('elem left', len(index)- count, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    if len(dvs)>1:
        for dv in dvs:
            series = df.iloc[i]
            series.loc['field3'] = dv
            serieses.append(list(series))

#create dataframe out of expanded rows now appended to serieses list, creating a list of lists
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(serieses,columns=df.columns)

### drop original rows with double entries, which have been expanded and appended already
indexes_to_drop = []
for i,dvs in zip(index,double_values):
    if len(dvs)>1:
        indexes_to_drop.append(i)

df.drop(df.index[indexes_to_drop],inplace=True)
len(df)


df = df.append(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach that would work for any condition.

```
condition = df["MaxPathID"] == 1
df = pd.concat([df, df[condition].copy()], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
  Date Completed  PathID  MaxPathID
0        1/31/17       1          3
1        1/31/17       2          3
2        1/31/17       3          3
3         2/1/17       1          1
4         2/2/17       1          2
5         2/2/17       2          2
6         2/1/17       1          1
```